How to properly bevel a sharp cube cut in the sphere?
I am trying to cut a sharp cube cut in the sphere, surprisingly, I could not find anywhere how it is properly done. In the picture you see a cut shape which I did by insetting face and extruding it inwards (no booleans here).  The problem appears when I want to make edges sharp in order to apply subdivision surface. I managed to make sharp edges on the top and bottom, but I can not manage to make sharp corners. I have tried using bevel (with different methods - arc, sharp, patch) or also different sequences of sharpening the edges, but without luck. The bevel particularly gives nasty artefacts.


You could select these edges as well:

Bevel, now your corner are sharp:

Correct the topology:

In the shared file, add this edge loop (CtrlR):

Move it slightly forward and you should not see any bad shape:


Thanks! I tried it, this works well on the plane, but it gives weird shading on the sphere. See the images https://imgur.com/a/1AY1GdG  Does it have to do with something like when I correct the topology, the vertices are moved and they do not form a perfect sphere?

Could you please share your object (just the part with the problem)

Here you go (note that I corrected the topology per your suggestion of only one corner): https://we.tl/t-iSGNqELRhB

@andrix I've edited my answer, I hope it helps

sorry for bugging you, I did as you showed, but there is still that same issue. from the angle you are showing it is not visible, but looking more from the side, it is there
